# how to test service property call

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, sinon

Here is my temp.js

```
angular.module('temp', [])
    .service('tempFactory', function() {
        this.a = 10;
    })
    .controller('tempCtrl', function($scope, tempFactory) {
        $scope.a = tempFactory.a;
    });
```

and here is my temp.Spec.js

```
describe('temp', function() {
    var ctrl, scope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('temp');

        inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.new();
            ctrl = $controller('tempCtrl', {$scope: scope});
        });
    });
});
```

I know that to test service method call it is necessary to use spy. But how to test service property call(in my code it is $scope.a = tempFactory.a;)? How can I find out
that some property of any service were called?

Answer (score 0):

Write a spec that tests the value on scope. No spy needed. Write something to the effect of:

```
it('sets a to the expected value from the service', function () {
  expect(scope.a).toBe(10);
});
```

Comment: Okay, if no spy needed then tell me please what do people use spies for? I know what spies do, I mean another. Just imagine I have such code: 


nameService = {
 getName: function() {return 'Pasha';}
};

$scope.test = function() { $scope.name = nameService.getName(); };

Comment: I need to test $scope.test method. If as you say no spy needed then I have to test only that after calling $scope.test(), $scope.name will have value of 'Pasha'? But in lots of articles and examles I saw that people tested not only value which would be set to scope property, they tested that nameService.getName was called using spies. If as you say no spy needed then what do people test method calling for? Why do not they only test value which will be set to scope property?

Comment: The reason I suggest that spy's are not needed here is because you asked about testing that the a property is set. You can not use a spy for properties. If you want to test that a method of a Controller, Directive, or Service functions as expected, then you should call the method with specific parameters and test that the state changed to match your expectations.

Comment: If you are looking for how spy's are to be used; they are typically used when you want to verify that a method is called on an object that is not currently under test. So, for example, if you want to test that your object dispatches an event when you call a specific method, the best way to do that is to listen for the event on the scope and pass it a spy so you will know that it has been called.

Comment: I typically use spy's for detecting when my "code under test" calls methods on objects not currently "under test." In other words to mock out objects that I am not currently testing, but that need to be there for the test code to work... aka dependencies.